# R legend not showing in Plot

Tags: r, plot, legend

I have the following R code for a simple plot:

```
ExperimentDataNames = c('Count', 'HumanData', 'ActualPrices')
ExperimentData <- read_csv("/Users/justin_chudley/desktop/ExperimentData.csv", col_names = ExperimentDataNames)

x <- Count <- ExperimentData$Count
y <- HumanData <- ExperimentData$HumanData
y1 <- ActualPrices <- ExperimentData$ActualPrices

plot(x,y, type = "l", xlab="Trial Number",ylab="$USD",main="Dow Jones Price vs Human Experiment")
lines(x,y1, type = "l", col=2)
legend=c('Human Data', 'Actual Prices')
```

The legend does not show at all in this plot for some reason: [image]

Why is my legend not showing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With your coding, you have assigned a vector of characters to an object named `legend`.

In order to add a legend, you need to use the `legend()` function.

```
legend(x = 10, y = 4e5, 
       col = c("black", "red"), lty = 1, lwd = 1,
       legend = c('Human Data', 'Actual Prices'))
```

You can use a heuristic approach by varying the values in `x` and `y` until you find a position you like. Alternatively, you can also set `x` to one of several predefined values:

```
legend(x = "top",
       col = c("black", "red"), lty = 1, lwd = 1,
       legend = c('Human Data', 'Actual Prices'))
```

Other options are to set `x` to "bottomright", "bottom", "bottomleft", "left", "topleft", "topright", "right" or "center".

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, I was reading the legend documentation but did not see this in there. Can you clarify how to represent a color next to the text in the legends? This shows a legend but does not have colors next to "human data" or "actual prices"

Comment: @user3357738 : I have added the `lty=1` and `lwd=1` parameters to give coloured lines. `lty=1` adds solid lines to the legend and `lwd` determined the thickness of the lines in the legend.

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much for the explanation and the solution!

Comment: Glad to hear that the answer was helpful :).